# Cause de la grimpée en flèche de l'utilisation de « et » de 1780 à 1800 avec une stabilisation qui se perpétue jusqu'au XXe

Tags: conjonctions, fréquence-utilisation

Comme on peut le voir à partir de la [courbe](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=et&year_start=1750&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cet%3B%2Cc0)<sup>1</sup>  d'utilisation dans la langue écrite, dans l'espace de vingt années la fréquence de l'emploi de ce mot n'a cessé d'augmenter jusqu'en 1800 puis s'est stabilisée sans jamais varier beaucoup jusqu'au temps présent; cela semble très bizarre, il faut qu'il y ait un contexte historique particulier qui explique cela. Le phénomène serait-il lié à une étape particulière de la révolution industrielle par exemple? Quelqu'un avec des bases dans ce domaine de la linguistique aurait-il la clé de cet étrange état de choses?

<sup>1</sup><sub>On constate que ce phénomène est beaucoup plus graduel pour le mot « [and](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=and&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cand%3B%2Cc0) » en anglais et correspond à la période qui suit la fin du moyen age anglais et l'avènement de l'imprimerie, c'est à dire la période de la Renaissance en Europe.</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Un graphique vaut mieux qu'un long discours :

[image]

La raison est donc l'obsolescence rapide de certaines ligatures, ici l'esperluète.

Comment: Réponse sans appel!

Comment: +1! J'en étais là! Eh oui! la ligature!

Comment: [Et la version qui somme les deux](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=et+%2B+%26&year_start=1750&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28et%20%2B%20%26%29%3B%2Cc0) intéressante aussi.